# err when using gscam

Tags: gscam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys

I tried to run gscam to get image from my camera but when I typed

```
$ roslaunch gscam v4l.launch
```

I got these errs:

```
[FATAL] [1400738699.774908523]: Failed to PAUSE stream, check your gstreamer configuration.
[FATAL] [1400738699.775082184]: Failed to initialize gscam stream!
```

and when I typed :

```
$rosrun gscam gscam
```

I got these errs:

```
[FATAL] [1400738785.074504579]: Problem getting GSCAM_CONFIG environment variable and 'gscam_config' rosparam is not set. This is needed to set up a gstreamer pipeline.
[FATAL] [1400738785.074717553]: Failed to configure gscam!
```

How can I fix these?

any suggestion about this?

thanks
hamid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167946/err-when-using-gscam/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Section 2](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam#Running) on the gscam wiki page describes how to the set the GSCAM_CONFIG environment variable; that should fix the second error you encountered.

You'll also want to make sure that you're using the correct video device, something like `/dev/video0` or `/dev/video1`, and that your user has read and write permissions on it.

I'm not sure why their v4l launch file doesn't work; it isn't documented on the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1